# Black spots on my ruby ficus elastica

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, diseases, fungus, ficus

Does anyone know what these black spots on my ficus are and how to treat? I had to put it out in the sun when my house was being painted, could it be sunburn? Or maybe a fungus?[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a fungus/virus/bacteria brought on by over watering.  Indicators are:

- happens on older growth first
- growth rings are present:  round hole in centre of dead tissue surrounded by a halo of dying tissue.  The disease grows a bit then stops then starts again.

Most plants can out grow this problem if you do the following:

- provide as much light as possible
- water less, only when the top inch of soil is dry
- ensure the plant is not sitting in water
- review the last time the plant was repotted.  If this is an old plant that has been overwatered it may be time to repot by

  - take out of pot
  - remove any black or soft roots
  - cut off an inch or two of the root ball at the bottom of the pot
  - add soil less mix to the bottom of the pot
  - replace plant in pot and water

Do not:

- fertilize until the spots stop appearing
- repot if the root system is firm with white or yellow roots

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and advice!